# IEnumerable<int> dataset pass from controller to VIEW and show or hide div sections according to that values on viewpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having following controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ValidateInput(false)]     
        public ActionResult Create_Template(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
        {
            // new you have access to all the ID's of the selected items, for example
            IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Property_ID);

            return View(selectedIDs);
        }
```

I want bind that `IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs` data values to view

Once I run this on debug mode normally those selectedIDs appear like this

[image]

So I want to pass those IEnumerable data set to view first and then show or hide div sections according to that values on viewpage

if I able to to bind data to view, I have palnned to show or hide div sections like below (appreciate your suggestions)

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create Templat";
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Create a Templat</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header"> .... </div>

        <div id="nav"> .... </div>

        <div id="section"> .... </div>

        <div id="footer"> .... </div>


    </body>
    </html>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {

                //using for loop read the array values index 0  to end:

                for(i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                if(array has value 1) $("#header").show()
                else $(#header").hide();

                if(array has value 2) $("#nav").show()
                else $("#nav").hide();

                if(array has value 3) $("#section").show()
                else $("#section").hide();

                .........

                }
});   

    </script> 
    }
```

So I'm looking for good way to do this

Comment: Why can't you just do the templating in the view instead of showing/hiding in JS?

Comment: @Saravana can you give me example of templating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you can define your model as `IEnumerable<int>` and use it to template like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<int>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Templat";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Templat</title>
</head>
<body>

    @if (Model.Contains(1))
    {
        <div id="header"> 1.... </div>
    }
    @if (Model.Contains(2))
    {
        <div id="nav"> 2.... </div>
    }
    @*and so on ...*@
    <div id="section"> .... </div>

    <div id="footer"> .... </div>

</body>
</html>
```

No need to do anything on the client side.